# Declaring INT variable to return in MYSQL Function problem

Tags: mysql, function, variables, insert

I'm trying to build a mysql function which inserts values into a table and returns me the last_id inserted, which should be the same after executing the insertion. But Xampp gives me an error in the line where im declaring the "last_bill_id" variable. Can someone please help me to understand what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code for the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION insert_bill(

        client_id varchar (12),
        bill_date date
    ) RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
        DECLARE last_bill INT; 
        INSERT INTO bill
        (
            client_id, bill_date
        )
         VALUES
        (
            client_id, bill_date
        );    
        SET last_bill = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        RETURN last_bill;  
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

Error: #1064 - Something is wrong about 'INT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need another DELIMITER at the start

```
DELiMiTER $$
CREATE FUNCTION insert_bill(

    client_id varchar (12),
    bill_date date
) RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTiC
BEGIN
    DECLARE last_bill INT; 
    INSERT INTO bill
    (
        client_id, bill_date
    )
     VALUES
    (
        client_id, bill_date
    );    
    SET last_bill := LAST_INSERT_ID();
    RETURN last_bill;  
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , the function got created, but when I execute this: SELECT insert_bill('111111111', STR_TO_DATE('18-03-2020', '%d-%m-%Y'); it gives me the same error

Comment: I removed the "DETERMINISTIC" and it worked, for my query: SELECT insert_bill2('111111111', STR_TO_DATE('14-03-2020', '%d-%m-%Y'))